# Basic javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have this function working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
      $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
      $.ajax({
        url: "loadmore.php?wall=<?php echo $wall; ?>&lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
        success: function(html) {
          if (html) {
            $("#postswrapper").append(html);
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
          } else {
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center><font color="white">No more posts to show.</font></center>');
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

But I need to have the same stuff happening (on IOS Devices), but instead of it happening when the browser reaches the `loadmoreajaxeloader` div, I simply need it to happen on an `onclick` event on a link. Thanks heaps.

Tried to add code but didn't format so here it is http://pastebin.com/p2VUqZff

Comment: Wrap the ajax code inside a function, then call that function when the link is clicked.

Comment: I have really low knowledge of javascript, how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the Ajax and the scroll event.

So create a function to load the content like so:

```
// Create the load content function
function loadContent(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "loadmore.php?wall=<?php echo $wall; ?>&lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
        success: function(html){
            if(html){
                $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
            }else{
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center><font color="white">No more posts to show.</font></center>');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then bind the scroll event to the window:

```
// Set the onscroll event
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()==$(document).height()-$(window).height()){
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        // IF YOU WANT TO LOAD MORE CONTENT WHEN SCROLLING THEN UNCOMMENT THE NEXT LINE
        // loadContent();
    }
});
```

Then set the onclick event of the Load More link:

```
// Bind the click event to the Load More link
$('#loadMore').click(function(e){
    // This will prevent any default action
    e.preventDefault();
    // Load the content
    loadContent();
});
```

**UPDATE**

I forgot to make sure the events are assigned once the page has loaded. Surround all of your javascript with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // PUT ALL THE JAVASCRIPT HERE
});
```

Comment: Great! So this would call the function?
 `<a href="javascript://" onclick="doSomething()">Load More</a>`

Comment: It would on the old one, but I have posted something new now. You do not need to assign an 'onlick' event inline like `onclick=""`. This is done with `$(element).bind({click:function(){}});`

Comment: @McDanGarrett I have amended the answer to do what you like. Make sure you replace '#loadMore' with your elements id. **You do not need to place any inline javascript with the above solution**

Comment: Okay, I have updated my function, to test it what is a link that could call the function without jumping to the top of the page?

Comment: @McDanGarrett I have just put it in, the line that reads `e.preventDefault()` should prevent this

Comment: A link does not have to have an `href` tag, however, I would use a `<span>` instead of an `<a>`

Comment: Didn't seem to work, I'm testing it on an iPod (the reason I need the link instead of just scrolling down) and when I click the link with the id of `loadMore` I get bumped to the top and the function does not work.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add something, give me a sec

Comment: @McDanGarrett The script was probably assigning handlers to things that had not be loaded and therefore were not being assigned. By adding the above, you tell the javascript to execute once the DOM has fully loaded

Comment: in the end of the click handler add `return false;`
it should prevent the link to execute its default action

Comment: @gpasci There should not be any need to do that because of the jQuery `preventDefault()` function. That is what it is there for!

Comment: Well I have just tried it and once again it bumps up and the function doesnt work, is it because it is on an ios device?

Comment: @McDanGarrett Nope, jQuery works on IOS. Can you add all of your HTML to the end of your answer, and I can then debug it

Comment: @McDanGarrett make sure your HTML is correct so the a tag should look like this (with or without the href). `<a id="loadMore">Load More</a>`. Notice that there is no # sign, this is an id selector for CSS and jQuery, I assume you know that though

Comment: I added that exact thing and it no longer bumps up but the function does nothing.

Comment: @McDanGarrett Add an `alert('hello')` to the function to see if it is being executed. I am having a look now. Are you definitely loading jQuery correctly?

Comment: I added `alert("test");` to the function but it did nothing, Im pretty sure the jQuery is working because the scroll function still works on a PC.

Comment: I am looking into it now. Have you got javascript turned on, on your iPod. If you dont know, it is in Settings->Safari->Javascript

Comment: Thanks heaps and Yes Javascript is on.

Comment: @McDanGarrett In the code you posted you have left out the 'e' in the click handler. Make sure it is changed from `click(function()...` to `click(function(e)...`

Comment: @McDanGarrett I have it working on my iPad and iPhone! I think it is most likely the 'e' problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9522/discussion-between-mcdan-garrett-and-ben-carey)

Answer (score 1):

If you're saying you want the code to execute both on scroll and when your link is clicked you can put the common code in a function that you call from all the places you need it:

```
function doStuff() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "loadmore.php?wall=<?php echo $wall; ?>&lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
    success: function(html) {
      if (html) {
        $("#postswrapper").append(html);
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
      } else {
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center><font color="white">No more posts to show.</font></center>');
      }
    }
  });
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
     $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
     doStuff();
  }
});

$("#idOfYourLinkGoesHere").click(function() {
   doStuff();
   return false;
});
```

Noting that returning false from the click handler stops the default behaviour for a click on a link (i.e., prevents it navigating away from the current page or moving back to the top of the page).

I wasn't sure if the `.show()` was to occur from the link so I've left it within the scroll handler. If it applies to either case move it into the `doStuff()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the scroll parts with something like that:

```
$('a#moreLoader').click(function() {
    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "loadmore.php?wall=<?php echo $wall; ?>&lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
            success: function(html) {
                if (html) {
                    $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                } else {
                    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center><font color="white">No more posts to show.</font></center>');
                }
             }
        });

        return false;
});
```

where `a#moreLoader` is a link with 'moreLoader' as id :

```
<a id="moreLoader" href="#">load more</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is "how can I *reuse* this function when a link is clicked" - and if so, the answer is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Declare the AJAX action as a separate function
  var loadMoreContent = function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "loadmore.php?wall=<?php echo $wall; ?>&lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
      success: function(html) {
        if (html) {
          $("#postswrapper").append(html);
          $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
        } else {
          $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center><font color="white">No more posts to show.</font></center>');
        }
      }
    });
  };

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
      $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
      loadMoreContent(); // Just call the separate function here
    }
  });

  // ...and attach the function as a click handler to the link:
  $('#idOfMyLink').click(function() {
    loadMoreContent(); // Just call the separate function here
    return false; // Return false to prevent navigation away from the page
  });

</script>
```